# wix burn installer requirements

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7

I was looking for some documentation which will explain what requirements of my installer will be if I made it with wix and burn...

I`m still not sure about that because that information is hard to get...
When I was looking for an answer i found [dependency of VC++redist...](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg09650.html) so it is telling me if I wrote custom action in c++ I need to have these on my target machine?

Also If I want to have my own UI, using burn... automatically I need .net framework 3.5?

I want to write installer, with custom actions and custom UI, I don`t mind which language use to write custom action (c++ or c#) but I want to be able to use my installation on winxp...

So if anybody have some info about requirements of installers... I did just couple of simple installers... all of them are running on win7 all right... but what about winxp? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that WiX is not an installation environment of its own. To put it simply, it is a comfortable, XML-style way to describe your installation requirements that gets translated into Windows Installer .msi databases by its compiler and linker. In this respect, WiX is a relatively thin wrapper around Windows Installer technology, and while it does provide extra features to help the setup developers, its abilities are dictated by the underlying technology and its limitations are not of its own but the limitations of Windows Installer itself.

System Requirements from Windows Installer 3.1 shows this:

Supported Operating System
Windows 2000 Service Pack 3, Windows 2000 Service Pack 4, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows XP Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 2
Windows Installer 3.1 Redistributable supports Windows 2000 with Service Pack 3 or later, Windows XP, Windows XP Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 2 and Windows Server 2003. Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 contains Windows Installer 3.1 and therefore can't be installed or upgraded by this redistributable.

So it should work like a charm on xp machines.

Sources: 
[WIX Tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started)
[MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25)

Comment: Well I`m not so sure about this... I don`t know find that link where I read about it, but I think that when you are using Burn... then there is some requirements... But yes, you`re right... if we are talking just about wix... without custom actions ( I mean written by me ) then it doesn`t need anything...

Comment: I just discover that if you wanna use MBA then you need .net framework 4

Comment: Good to know that, the requirements which I mentioned above was just for WIX and not for WIX burn then.

Comment: Well looks like I was wrong about it... [Rob](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-the-MbaNetfxPackageId-and-MbaPreqPackageName-variables-td6554261.html) is saying that it should work also with lower version of .net framework... so mistake is on my side :)